# Eclipse: Making Eclipse's "search in project" less unhelpful?

Tags: eclipse, search, ack

Eclipse's "find in project" took is, as far as I can tell, blindingly stupid.

Let me illustrate. This is what I get when I run a "find in project":

[find in project http://img.skitch.com/20100312-qgpi9jwyyb6qudc656j1j1tne3.png](http://img.skitch.com/20100312-qgpi9jwyyb6qudc656j1j1tne3.png)

And when I click to see what's in that "closed" `skinning` folder I get...

[even more unhelpful http://img.skitch.com/20100312-r7cjk9a9sjix3y2694361ytsd4.png](http://img.skitch.com/20100312-r7cjk9a9sjix3y2694361ytsd4.png)

... and so on.

So **how can I make this more helpful**? Am I doing something wrong?

Ideally, I'd like to see something along the lines of, say, `ack`, the tool I normally use:

[useful! http://img.skitch.com/20100312-gixej3w617qpibrm79c8w78j1f.png](http://img.skitch.com/20100312-gixej3w617qpibrm79c8w78j1f.png)

Comment: Good rant.  Maybe get a blog though?

Comment: Ok, yes, sorry… It is a bit ranty… I've edited it to make the question clearer, though. Hopefully it's a bit better now.

Comment: Thank you for verbalizing a pain point that I've also been experiencing.

Answer (score 3):

Clicking the "Expand All" icon (the tiled squares with + on the front one) can help, but I don't think you can hide the top level items.

Comment: Ah, I completely missed that button. Good to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

How about using the little triangle menu in the search results, and selecting "View as List"?

Comment: Awesome! Now it shows me all the files… But not the matching lines. Is there any way to get it to show those, too?

Comment: Yeah, that's sort of annoying that you can't see the lines in that mode.